# Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 (Vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing my project in Vb.net. my project name is "Bellows". My front end is Vb.net. Back end is Ms Access.
i Create My project in Windows Application

i complete my project. i copy the .exe file from "E:\BellowNet(new)\Bellows\obj\Debug" and put the shortcut into my desktop. now it's running.

similarly i copied my Bellows.exe from another system desktop but it not running.

How i want to run my Bellows.exe from another systems (maximum 10 systems).

Note : In my system only having Microsoft Visual Studio 2005. Remaining system doesn't have.

I put bellows.exe from another system. in that system doesn't having E Drive. it showing this error

The application Filed to initialize properly(0xc0000135). Click Ok to terminate the application

Similarly I put bellows.exe from another system. in that system having E Drive.

if i click that Bellows.exe the login form is open.. and main form is open. in that main form wen i click button it show the error.

Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If u click continue the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If u click Quit, the application will close immediately. Could not load file or assembly ‘ADODB, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublickeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a’ or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: You didn't mention the type of project is Windows or WebApp. Also you need to install .net framework in all the system you want to run.

Comment: Accounts and questions merged.  Please do not close as dupe.

Answer (score 2):

Good practice to run your project on another systems is to create its setup file and then install it on to another systems on which you want to run your project and of course you need to install .NetFramework as well with the same version which you used to developed your project. How to create setup and how to add Serial Key for those steps [refer my blog](http://rupeshit.wordpress.com/2009/12/28/setup-and-deployment-and-serialkey-in-vs-net/)

Comment: Yes, always create a setup file for deployment. This ensures that all of your application's dependencies are installed on the target machine with a minimal amount of fuss. The built-in support for this in Visual Studio is very good. And compile in Release mode.

Comment: sir in 8 step i click the start from user interface but it not showing install header and add licence agreement,Customer information.. it shows only Add Dialog and Properties sir..

Comment: @D Narasimhulu : In Add Dialog these options are present!!! If still you have any problem let me know....If these steps solved your problem then accept solutions so that other can also refer it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like either the .Net Framework is not installed on your target system or that there's an app.config file (Bellows.app.config) that you need to copy over as well.

Another thing that concerns me is what your expectations are for the access database.  Do you want all the workstations to share a common database?  If so, I highly recommend you convert your app to use Sql Server Express Edition (free).  Access is an in-process database engine, and like all such engines it doesn't behave well when shared.  If you don't expect them to share the database, you probably want to make sure you copy that *.mdb file over to your target machines as well.

Finally, let me re-iterate the advice in other answers about using a Release build and/or deployment project.

Answer (score 0):

What errors do you see?

It could be:

- The other system does not have .Net
  framework 2.0 installed
- You copied only the exe from the dev machine without other required files from the Debug directory (e.g., app.config, supporting DLLs).

Comment: **You should never copy files to another machine from the Debug directory.** If you're *deploying* your application, you should compile in *Release* mode and copy the files from that folder. The choice of names was not merely a curious coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to copy and paste the exe file then the all Prerequiest should be installed on that machine like framework.So make a setup file which is easy and add all Prerequiest on the setup after that do setup on new machine..

Thanks

Comment: how i want to create setup for my project

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but try this suggestions.

> The application Filed to initialize
>   properly(0xc0000135). Click Ok to
>   terminate the application

.NET framework is not installed on this machine. Install the runtime.

> Could not load file or
>   assembly ‘ADODB, Version=7.0.3300.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublickeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a’ or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified

ADO.NET drivers are missing. You need to install [Microsoft Data Access Components](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6c050fe3-c795-4b7d-b037-185d0506396c)

You can avoid this problems if you make an install procedure and do the proper install on every machine.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate .NET framework must be installed in each machine as well as the appropriate MDAC. You can add them as part of the installation package.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994427.aspx

And if you want to make it even more easier for your clients to get hold of it; use ClickOnce to distribute it from a central server.

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/041229.htm